# Copy appended data to a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following which is working in the same workbook how do I get this to use a summary sheet in a different workbook?

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ws.Range("D2:D6, D8:D15").Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: see [`this`](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/various-ways-to-pull-data-out-of-a-closed-or-opened-workbook-using-excel-formulas-and-vba/) for tips

Comment: workbooks("other workbook path").sheets("summary").activate.  Note: the other workbook (I think) needs to be open for this to work.

Comment: I have to ammend my answer. I haven't had to reference external workbooks in a while so I'm a little rusty. **Edit** Okay, I tested it successfully. My first example was correct, I just didn't have both workbooks open in the same Excel instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you place the sub-routine in a `Module`, and not in
   `ThisWorkbook`. You can insert a new module by right-clicking on workbook name (from the VBA editor) and going to **Insert** > **Module**.
2. Make sure the workbooks you want to use/reference are open.
3. Make sure the workbooks are all located in the same workbook collection. This is not a problem unless you manually create an additional instance of Excel.
4. Reference the workbooks using the `Workbooks()` object just like you
   do with Worksheets.

   ```
   Sub test()


   Dim b2 As Workbook 'We will use this variable as a reference to the external workbook that contains the "Summary" worksheet.

   Set b2 = Excel.Workbooks("testbook2") 'We assign the external workbook (which I named "testbook2" for the purposes of this example) to our 'b2' variable.

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet 'We will use these variables as references to the worksheets we're using.

   Set ws1 = Excel.ActiveSheet 'We set ws1 to equal our current sheet (which presumably is where you'll be copying data from).
   Set ws2 = b2.Worksheets("Summary") 'We set ws2 to equal the sheet (named "Summary") in the external workbook (named "testbook2").

   ws1.Range("D2:D6").Copy 'We copy the data from the active sheet, which we reference using our 'ws1' variable. 
   'Note: I had issues with using multiple ranges in the same object so I removed this from your code.
   ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'You only need to use the ws2 variable since we've already defined it as the "Summary" sheet you want.


   End Sub
   ```

I'm not sure why I follow that first rule, but I seem to remember having issues when using `ThisWorkbook` in conjunction with external workbook references.

### Update

I edited the code to show you a better example of how to do this. You almost never need to use "Activate" or "Select" commands in VBA. Just assign variables and reference the values directly.

Comment: sorry i am very very new to this what do I do with your code add it to my existing before the end sub?

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation much appreciated. however when I ran the module it gave an error message 1004 'the selection method is not valid' this may be due to several reasons etc.... do you know why this may have happened? and also how do I get it to append data from a second, third or fourth sheet the the workbook

Comment: @Steve Well my guess would be that selecting multiple ranges like this `.Range("D2:D6, D8:D15")` cannot be used with `.Copy`. The alternative is to use `.Select` to assign the ranges to the "selection" and then use `Selection.Copy` to copy that selection, but if I were you, I would just copy/paste one range at a time. It's much easier and you probably shouldn't complicate things too much since you're just learning it.